# ReactJS Post with Express, GraphQL, and SQLite3

Tags: reactjs, express, sqlite, graphql

I am trying to post data to a SQLite DB from a form. Very new at React so please bear with me.

Now in my `Register.js` form code, I have an `action="/graphql"`. I'm hung up on how exactly to route that `POST` to my graphql mutation code and ultimately to a SQLite insert (which I'm still missing I believe).

Please take a look and let me know any suggestions on how to proceed.

Also here is my latest working branch: [Github](https://github.com/ahummel25/classroom-portal/tree/hummela-branch-2)

Part of `server.js` that handles `graphql`:

```
app.use( '/graphql', expressGraphQL(req => ({
    schema,
    graphiql: false,
    rootValue: { request: req },
    pretty: __DEV__,
  }))
);
```

`Register.JS` form:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes, { func } from 'prop-types';
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';
import s from './Register.css';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

let postURL = 'http://localhost:3000/graphql';

class Register extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      schoolName: '',
      userName: '',
      password: '',
    };
    this.onSchoolNameChange = this.onSchoolNameChange.bind(this);
    this.onUserNameChange = this.onUserNameChange.bind(this);
    this.onPasswordChange = this.onPasswordChange.bind(this);
  }

  onSchoolNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({ schoolName: event.target.value });
  }

  onUserNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({ userName: event.target.value });
  }

  onPasswordChange(event) {
    this.setState({ password: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit = () => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    const { schoolName, userName, password } = this.state;
    console.log(postURL);
    fetch(postURL, {
      mode: 'no-cors',
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "type": "formData"
      },
      body: this.state
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      alert("Submitted!");
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  };

  render() {
    const { schoolName, userName, password } = this.state;
    const isEnabled =
      schoolName.length > 0 && userName.length > 0 && password.length > 0;
    return (
      <div className={s.root}>
        <div className={s.container}>
          <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
          <form action="/graphql" method="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className={s.formGroup}>
              <label className={s.label} htmlFor="schoolName">
                School Name:
                <input
                  className={s.input}
                  id="schoolName"
                  type="text"
                  name="schoolName"
                  value={this.state.schoolName}
                  onChange={this.onSchoolNameChange}
                  autoFocus // eslint-disable-line jsx-a11y/no-autofocus
                />
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className={s.formGroup}>
              <label className={s.label} htmlFor="userName">
                User Name:
                <input
                  className={s.input}
                  id="userName"
                  type="text"
                  name="userName"
                  value={this.state.userName}
                  onChange={this.onUserNameChange}
                />
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className={s.formGroup}>
              <label className={s.label} htmlFor="password">
                Password:
                <input
                  className={s.input}
                  id="password"
                  type="password"
                  name="password"
                  value={this.state.password}
                  onChange={this.onPasswordChange}
                />
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className={s.formGroup}>
              <button disabled={!isEnabled} className={s.button} type="submit">
                Submit
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(s)(Register);
```

`Schema.js`:

```
import {
GraphQLSchema as Schema,
  GraphQLObjectType as ObjectType,
} from 'graphql';

import mutation from './mutations/mutation'

const schema = new Schema({
  mutation: mutation
});

export default schema;
```

`sequelize.js`:

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import config from '../config';

const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.databaseUrl, {
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: './database.sqlite',
  define: {
    freezeTableName: true,
  },
});

export default sequelize;
```

`Mutation.js`:

```
import {GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString} from 'graphql';
import SchoolType from '../types/SchoolType';

const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'SchoolMutation',
    fields: {
        registerSchool: {
            type: SchoolType,
            description: 'Register a new school',
            args: {
                id: {
                    name: 'id',
                    type: GraphQLString
                },
                userName: {
                    name: 'userName',
                    type: GraphQLString
                },
                password: {
                    name: 'password',
                    type: GraphQLString
                }
            },
            resolve: (root, {id, userName, password}) => {
                //do something??? call db?
            }
        }
    }
});

export default Mutation;
```

`SchoolType.js`:

```
import {
   GraphQLObjectType as ObjectType,
   GraphQLString as StringType,
   GraphQLNonNull as NonNull,
} from 'graphql';

const SchoolType = new ObjectType({
    name: 'School',
    fields: {
      id: { type: new NonNull(StringType) },
      userName: { type: new NonNull(StringType) },
      password: { type: StringType },
    },
  });

  export default SchoolType;
```

Comment: the `onSubmit` event will receive an event as an argument. You should be able to access the form and it's action from that event. `e.currentTarget.action` I believe

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j0xv7xxf/

Comment: @CoryDanielson So my main issue is once I receive that event, how do I route my post to a GraphQL/SQLite DB transaction?